# best way to manage code on javascript for re usability and future scalability

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm trying to bring out oop from javascript language. We have few functions that sends JSON data to server. sendChanges function basically converts the object to JSON format and send to the server. The code works fine, the problem is we will create those type of functions a lot and want to find a best manageable way of doing it so if we do any change to the parameters names, we should be able to point out in the javascript quick and easy way. In the below code "title", "phtotid", "userName", "action", "parameters" need to be type safe both in the server and javascript.

```
var reloadew = function () {
    _self.sendChanges({
        "action": "reload",
        "parameters": {}
    });
};

var reloadallew = function () {
    _self.sendChanges({
        "action": "reloadall",
        "parameters": {}
    });

};
var reloadAllChat = function () {
    _self.sendChanges({
        "action": "reloadChat",
        "parameters": {}
    });

};
var createew = function (param1, param2, param3) {
    _self.sendChanges({
        "action": "createew",
        "parameters": {
            "title": param1,
            "phtotId": param2,
            "userName": param3
        }
    }, "definition");
};
var joinew = function (param1, param2) {
    _self.sendChanges({
        "action": "joinew",
        "parameters": {
            "phtotId": param1,
            "userName": param2
        }
    }, "definition");
};
```

Comment: I would create a configuration object if it's likely that the fields will need to be renamed, however, as it is, this question is really, really broad.

Comment: can you give an example how you will create configuration object?

Comment: A configuration object can be anything from a simple one-to-one mapping to requesting field names from the server over Ajax.